# Wäsche auf links drehen

Tags: etymology

Wieso dreht man Wäsche *auf links*, wenn man sie doch eigentlich von innen nach außen dreht?

Google hat mir leider dieses Mal leider, abgesehen von [gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/wieso-heisst-es-waesche-auf-links-machen) nicht weiter geholfen, sondern hat mir nur viele Waschtipps ausgespuckt.

Comment: Duden ignoriert diese Bedeutung (umgedrehtes Wäschestück) erstaunlicherweise vollkommen, das Grimmsche Wörterbuch kennt sie als *verkehrt, gewendet*.

Comment: @tofro „auf links drehen“ findet man auch im Duden (z. B. in Band 2 oder im großen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) sowie auf [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/node/639981/revisions/1372035/view), allerdings ohne Erklärung der Herkunft.

Comment: @Loong nicht mal mit Erklärung - als ob "links" und "gewendet" dasselbe wäre. Ich finde, das hätte eine eigene Bedeutung verdient gehabt.

Comment: @Loong, den Artikel im Duden hatte ich auch gesehen, aber da steht nirgends was von Wäsche oder von innen nach außen umdrehen.

Comment: _"Das kommt davon ,das früher viele Sachen gestrickt waren. und da gibt es beim Stricken immer rechte und Linke Maschen. Die äußere oder schönere Seite ist die rechte Seite (man sagt auch Warenseite dazu). Und somit ist etwas nach links drehen eben die innere Seite nach außen drehen."_ Gefunden bei http://www.cosmiq.de/qa/show/2050123/Auf-links-drehen/ - kann aber nicht sagen ob das stimmt :)

Comment: @Knut: Ist aber eine alternative Wahrheit zur Erklärung Ingmars - vielleicht machst Du eine Antwort draus?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das vom Stricken kommt. Die viel ältere Form ist das Weben. Hier gibt es eine Webart, die Köperbindung, bei der unterschiedlich viele Kettfäden unter- oder überfahren werden. Bei jedem Schuss wird diese Grenze zwischen oben und unten nach rechts verschoben. Damit ist das "rechte Warenbild" die Seite, bei der der Weber nach rechts gearbeitet hat. Die andere Seite wird dann folgerichtig als linke Seite bezeichnet. Das rechte Warenbild wiederum ist die schönere Webseite, auf der das gewünschte Farbmuster am besten zu sehen ist.

Comment: @IQV: klingt ganz plausibel und viele Wörter stammen tatsächlich aus dem Weberhandwerk. Allerdings habe ich auch Referenzen gefunden, die bei Stoffen von **zwei rechten Seiten** (vorne und hinten) reden.

Comment: Richtig, das ist die Leinwandbindung. Dort ist die Anzahl der Kettfäden gleich und deshalb unterscheiden sich Vorder und Rückseite nicht. Das ist die einfachste Webtechnik, z. B. immer abwechselnd oben - unten -...

Comment: @IQV damit fällt das ganze aber wieder zurück auf "rechts" == "richtigrum" wie in Ingmars Antwort

Comment: @tofro Im Prinzip ja. Aber bei der Leinwandbindung wird dann auch oft von zwei "rechten Warenbildern" gesprochen, da Vorder- und Rückseite gleich sind. Da gibt es dann kein linkes Warenbild und man kann das Gewebe auch nicht "auf links drehen".

Answer (score 15):

Ich glaube es besteht ein Zusammenhang mit "rechts = richtig", demgemäß wäre dann alles was links ist, falsch (vgl. "eine Linke" etc.) Demnach wäre die "rechte Seite" die richtige und die "linke Seite" die falsche, verkehrte.

Comment: +1, vgl. auch "linkisch" und "jmd. linken", beides mit Konnotation "falsch"

Comment: Und auch schon im Lateinischen hat *sinister* die Nebenbedeutung von "fies", "Unglück bringend" oder "drohend", also eine negative Konnotation

Comment: Das ist aber nicht mehr als eine Vermutung, oder?

Comment: Das wäre auch meine Vermutung, aber stimmt sie?

Comment: +1 Hier eine Referenz zu den Grimms, wo diese Bedeutung unter 2) und 4) genau so genannt wird: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL06176#XGL06176

Comment: @Takkat, Grimm sagt nur, dass _links_ zwei Bedeutungen hat, allerdings sagt es ja nicht, dass die eine Bedeutung die zweite Bedeutung herleitet.

Comment: @Iris: unter [recht(s)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GR02054#XGR02054) sagen sie: *recht, bei dingen die zu wenden sind, bezeichnet die gewöhnlich sichtbare oder obere seite (vgl. dazu link)*

Comment: *Verkehrt* kommt demnach auch von *kehren* in einer überaus seltenen, eigentlich nicht im Ansatz wahrhaftigen Bedeutung von "falsch"? So wie diese Antwort???

Answer (score -3):

> **lenken** Vb. ‘in eine bestimmte Richtung bewegen, steuern’, mhd. lenken ‘biegen, wenden, richten’ […] Die Bedeutung entwickelt sich von ‘biegen, in eine andere Richtung biegen’ zu ‘die Richtung bestimmen, steuern’. – **ablenken** Vb. ‘in eine andere Richtung lenken, abbiegen’ (um 1500), ‘fernhalten, abwenden, auf andere Gedanken bringen’ (Anfang 16. Jh.).

Damit zusammenhängend

> **Gelenk** n. ‘bewegliche Verbindung von Knochen, von (Maschinen)bauteilen’, ahd. gi(h)lenki (11./12. Jh.), mhd. gelenke […] sind verwandt mit aengl. *hlanc* ‘schlank, dünn’, eigentlich ‘biegsam’, aengl. *hlence*, anord. *hlekkr* ‘Kette, Kettenglied’, *hlykkr* ‘Krümmung, Biegung’ und mit lat. *clingere* ‘umgürten, schließen’. –

> „lenken“ und „Gelenk“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), digitalisierte und von Wolfgang Pfeifer überarbeitete Version im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Gelenk, abgerufen am 10.09.2023.

Wegen "schlank, dünn" ließe sich vermutlich ein vermutlich doch eher zufälliger Zusammenhang mit der Linken, *schwachen Hand* vermuten. Pfeifer (cf. *links*) stellt die übliche Herleitung ebenso in Frage, "Oder im Sinne von ‘gebogen, schief’ (im Gegensatz zu recht ‘gerade’, s. d.) verwandt mit *lenken, Gelenk*?" begründet es aber anders, um den Zusammenhang mit mittelhochdeutsch *linc, lenk* "link, linkisch, unwissend" zu retten.

Der weit verbreitete, nicht gänzlich unbegründete Gedanke, dass die linke Hand des Teufels sei, kann nur als gepflegte Volksetymologie begriffen werden.

> Next to *laevus* and *scaevus*, the meaning 'left' for *sinister* must be a more recent
> development. […] WH connect the root **senh₂* 'to obtain' (Skt. *sanóti*), which would imply something like 'the more favourable
> (side)' for **senH-is-tero-* > *sinister*.

> [M. de Vaan, Etymological Dictionary of Latin; *WH* = *Walde/Hofmann*, Lateinisches etymologisches Wörterbuch]

Die ungelenke Herleitung aus der Anatomie überzeugt insoweit nicht wirklich, da außergermanische Anknüpfungspunkte nicht gesichert sind. Unterdessen vergleicht De Vaan tatsächlich altisländisch *hlekkr* 'chain, ring', usw. und rekonstruiert althochdeutsch *lenk**, *lenc** 'left', doch warnt hinsichtlich *clingere, -ō*: "The precarious transmission of this word in Latin renders its linguistic reality uncertain." Dessen baltoslavische Vergleiche unterstreichen nur die Unsicherheit.

Zu mhd. *linc* ~ *linkes* heißt es letztendlich auch nur "origin uncertain" (en.WT: links).

---

Zum Vergleich bietet sich maßgeblich an *rücklinks* / *rücklings*, mhd. *rückelingen*,  althochdeutsch *ruggilingūn* ‘rückwärts, hinten’ (Pfeifer/dwds.de). Zur Endung:

> Daß das *l* dieses Wortbildungselements erst sekundär angetreten ist (wohl analog zu Ableitungen, die zum Wortstamm gehörendes *-l-* enthalten, vgl. etwa ahd. *hālingon, -un* ‘heimlich’, *ītalingūn* ‘vergeblich’, zu *Hehl* bzw. *eitel*, s. d.), zeigen die in früher Zeit gleichermaßen nachweisbaren Adverbien auf ahd. *-ingū̌n, -ingon* [usw.]

> „-lings“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993) [*ibid.*]

S.a. EWA: ahd. [*-iling*](https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/-iling/de#-iling), "wobei *-il-* die Dimi-
nution, *-ing* die Zugehörigkeit ausdrückt.", was jedoch nicht ganz dasselbe ist.

Dies gereicht zum Schluss der Vermutung, die Polysemy von "links" habe einerseits zu dieser Entwicklung (s. *rücklings*) beitragen können, müsste in Ihrer Entstehung im Einzelfall (*links*) aber ganz anders begründet werden. Das ist an dieser Stelle nicht zu leisten.

Weil ein appelativer Wortstamm **auf-l-* oder ähnliches nicht offensichtlich ist und die Analogie ansonsten beliebig ist, d.h. unbegründet, ist eine sekundäre Ableitung (s. *-lings*) im Fall von "auf links drehen" nicht unwahrscheinlich.

---

Denkbar wäre zwar mittelhochdeutsch *afel*<sup>a)</sup>, sofern dies neben mitteldeutsch *äbich* "das abstehende, zurückstehende, folglich verkehrte und linke" (DWB; "inside out", en.WT) unter niederdeutscher Vermittlung<sup>b)</sup> in mhd. *afel*, *aver*, *ävern, äfern*, *äffic-lich* o.ä. (s. Lexer, DWB) aufgegangen zu sein scheint

<sub>a) s. en.WT: [*aflą](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/afl%C4%85) "power, strength, might", jedoch ohne Definition für mhd.</sub>

<sub>b) s. en.WT: [*abuhaz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/abuhaz) "turned the wrong way, inverted;
wicked, bad"; EWA: ahd. [abuh](https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/abuh/de#abuh), vgl. mndl. *āves, aefs* "verkehrt", ae.
*afu(h)lic* "perversus", me. *awk(e), auk(e)* "from the left, perverse, strange", aisl. *ǫfugr* "verkehrt, abgewandt" etc.</sub>

---

Eine andere Möglichkeit wird im Weben gesehen (s. die Kommentare, @knut), die Zusammenhänge sind jedoch ungewiss. Grimm bemerkte einst *afner*, das "*eher zu* weben *selbst gehört, und dem altn.* ofnir *textor? ([…]) gleicht, dem bekannten* webel, wefel *panucla verwandt*." (DWB: [afner](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/afner)) Zweitens kann mit altnordisch *hlekkr* "Kettenglied" ein Rückschloss auf die angesprochene Richtung der Masche beim Stricken bzw. Weben verstanden werden: bei Läufern, Baumwollsocken usw. ist die Oberseite glatt, nur auf der Unterseite befinden sich viele feine Knoten.

<sub>Deswegen kommt unter der Annahme eines nordischen Lautwandels *o* < *wo* für das gesuchte Appelativum die Wortfamilie um *weben* in betracht, nämlich ... *Waffel*? "Die Bezeichnung für das alte niederländische Fasten- und Festgebäck, die von der wabenartigen Musterung ausgeht," (Pfeifer: *Waffel*). Siehe ferner im Niederländischen: "Ontwikkeld uit Proto-Germaans **wēb-ilō-*, […] vernoemd naar haar geweven patroon, net zoals een honingraat" [Philippa *et al.*, Etymologisch Woordenboek van het Nederlands, https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/wafel)), "oorspr. = “weefsel”: germ. **wêƀlô-*, ablautend met *weven*."  (N. van Wijk (1936 [1912]), Franck's Etymologisch woordenboek der Nederlandsche taal [*ibid.*]) Zum Thema steht da natürlich nichts. Die Ähnlichkeit zu *Oblate* ist auch eher zufällig, dessen Herleitung aus *offere, ob-fero*, im Bezug auf urindogermanische Partikeln och viele Fragen offen lässt, insbesondere ob **wêƀ-* zu einer solchen gehört wie *auf-* < **upó*.</sub>

Obscura per obscurum.

Comment: Was hat das mit der Frage zu tun?

Comment: @Kritiker, spezifiziere "das". Hat die Edith geholfen?

Comment: @userunknown dein Edit ist wieder mal nonsense. Dieses mal sogar inhaltlich, nicht nur auf meine eigenwillige Schreibe bezogen.

Comment: und die downvotes sind herkömmliches Scheuklappengehabe.

Comment: Wieso rollst Du sie dann nicht zurück? Und was heißt "wieder mal"? Bislang hast Du mir noch keine Nonsense-edits vorgeworfen - auch sonst erinnere ich mich an derartige Vorwürfe. Ganz billiges Framing!

Comment: Ja, Dein Edit hat den Zusammenhang mit der Frage deutlich gemacht. Trotzdem für mich kein Grund für ein Upvote. Auch vorher  war es übrigens für mich kein Grund für ein Downvote.

Comment: @KritikerDerElche, dass "wenden" (s. erstes Zitat) relevant ist, bedürfte das weiterer Ausführung oder lenkt (bzw. *wendet*) dies doch zu sehr ab? Dass *hlenk* im Ansatz auf das Weben zu beziehen ist (vgl *ketteln*?), schien mir letztendendes nicht mehr zielführend, erklärt aber den Ansatz. Ist das etwa nicht offensichtlich? Und wieso sollte ich versuchen, irgendwen zu überzeugen, wenn irgendein swagsinn enrgegensteht und es ausreichen sollte, hinreichende Zweifel darzustellen?